# Show save button after changing textbox(react,redux,material ui)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a project with react,redox and material-ui. there are some textfields on page and I want to show save button only when at least one of textfields is changed. I could add some function to onChange of textfields and set isDirty to true and show button when this property set to true. but I'm wondering is there any clean and good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using Redux. I am suggesting you to have a look at Redux Form - https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form

In redux form, after you initialize the redux form on your component, you may use Field component for each of your input.

```
    <Field component="input" type="text" />
```

By using the reduxForm High-order component, it will inject some of the props like dirty,pristine,touch etc.. which helps you to show or hide your button.

```
    export default reduxForm({
       form: 'formName' // a unique identifier for this form
    })(YourComponent)
```